# Orchard how to access Model part in Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a model that contains a veriable. I would like to access that veriable in controller but I am not having any luck. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

My models:

```
public class Interspire_MailingPart : ContentPart<Interspire_MailingPartRecord>
{
    [Required]
    public String SubscribeFormID
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.SubscribeFormID); }
        set { Store(r => r.SubscribeFormID, value); }
    }
}

public class Interspire_MailingPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual String SubscribeFormID { get; set; }
}
```

I set them when I add the widget. My migration and everything is ok.

EDIT:
To clarify what I am trying to do:
I want my module to have 2 different kind of settings. One that will be on site level so that every widget will have the same. Then on the widget level so every widget you add will have different setting.

And I want to access both settings in my controller.

But I can only access the globalsetting but localsetting return an emptystring.

Controller

```
public class MailControllerWebApi : ApiController
{
    public MailControllerWebApi(IOrchardServices orchardServices)
    {
        Services = orchardServices;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
     }

    public IOrchardServices Services { get; private set; }
    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public string Get(string Email) {
        var localSettings = Services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<Interspire_MailingPart>();
        var globalSettings = Services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<Interspire_MailingSettingsPart>();

        return localSettings.SubscribeFormID;

    } 
}
```

Both handlers:

```
public class MailingSettingsHandler: ContentHandler
{
    public MailingSettingsHandler(IRepository<Interspire_MailingSettingsPartRecord> repository)
    {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<Interspire_MailingSettingsPart>("Site"));
        Filters.Add(new TemplateFilterForPart<Interspire_MailingSettingsPart>("Nastavitve", "Parts/MailingSettings", "Interspire"));
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context) {
        if (context.ContentItem.ContentType != "Site")
            return;
        base.GetItemMetadata(context);
        context.Metadata.EditorGroupInfo.Add(new GroupInfo(T("Interspire")));
    }
}

public class MailingHandler: ContentHandler
{
    public MailingHandler(IRepository<Interspire_MailingPartRecord> repository)
    {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<Interspire_MailingPart>("Site"));
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
    public Localizer T { get; set; }
}
```

And the driver:

```
public class MailingDriver : ContentPartDriver<Interspire_MailingPart>
{
    private readonly IOrchardServices _services;

    public MailingDriver(INotifier notifier, IOrchardServices services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(Interspire_MailingPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var mailingSettings = _services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<Interspire_MailingSettingsPart>();
        return ContentShape("Parts_Mailing",
            () => shapeHelper.Parts_Mailing(
                Url: mailingSettings.Url,
                SubscribeFormID: part.SubscribeFormID
            ));
    }

    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(Interspire_MailingPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Mailing_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/Mailing",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(Interspire_MailingPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

Globalsettings get data normaly, but localsetting just return an empty string.

EDIT2
Migration file:

```
public int Create() {

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("InterspireMailingWidget", cfg => cfg
          .WithPart("Interspire_MailingPart")
          .WithPart("WidgetPart")
          .WithPart("CommonPart")
          .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("Interspire_MailingPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column("SubscribeFormID", DbType.String)
        );

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("Interspire_MailingSettingsPartRecord", table => table
             .ContentPartRecord()
             .Column("Url", DbType.String)
         );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("Interspire_MailingPart",
          builder => builder.Attachable());

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Still not clear. What you seem to call local settings are just properties on parts of your widget, right? Do you already have a reference to that widget?

Comment: It would be worth showing us everything to be sincere. it seems you are missing some of the basics here.

Comment: Yes local settings are just properties on parts of my widget. 
What else do you need? The migration?

Comment: I have added migration.cs, I dont know what else you need since this is now more or less all of the code. I dont know what I am doing wrong but both setting get written into the database and I can normally access both in my Views, but I can only get to "Globalsettings" in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show us your controller's code? 
Usually you would inject IContentManager or grab it from IOrchardServices and use _contentManager.Get(...) or _contentManager.Query(...), check those out. 
Google that and you will see how others do it.

Comment: I added controller, handlers and driver. And an explanation of what I am trying do acomplish. Hope you can help my why I can access "globalsetting" through IOrchardServices but can't do the same for "localsettings"